Is there a way to compare hypothetical radii of lanthanide(II) ions with measured radii of Eu(II), Dy(II), Tm(II), Yb(II)?
Not all the lanthanides occur as divalent cations in compounds. I want to estimate the radii of hypothetical 2+ lanthanide ions so that it is theoretically consistent with the observed values for coordination number VI:

$\ce{La^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Ce^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Pr^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Nd^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Pm^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Sm^2+}$ no data
$\ce{Eu^2+}$ $\pu{117 pm}$
$\ce{Gd^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Tb^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Dy^2+}$ $\pu{107 pm}$
$\ce{Ho^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Er^2+}$ non-existent
$\ce{Tm^2+}$ $\pu{103 pm}$
$\ce{Yb^2+}$ $\pu{102 pm}$

For my purposes, it is OK to have about 3 picometers error. Is there a theory for filling in the gaps in the list above?

https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(91)90388-X, Table I, column “$N=6$”.


Is there a theory for filling in the gaps in the list above?

I think you cannot fill the gap by using a "theory" with $\pm\pu{3 pm}$ accuracy, yet you can assume the radii of ions, which are getting smaller with increasing atomic number as you have already seen (see your own list of available ionic radii) due to Lanthanide Contraction (Ref.1). Nonetheless, your "non-existent" label for most of lanthanide ion is not correct since there are few publication on crystal radii and effective ionic radii are already existing as one found by Andselisk. I list here the list of ionic radii ($\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{C} =$ crystal radii and $\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{E} =$ effective ionic radii) for all of divalent lanthanide ions you have listed (coordination number VI) from two references (Ref.2 & 3) together with thermodynamic ionic radii, $\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{TD}$, given as $r_1$ and $r_2$ in Ref.4 as well:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Lanthanide} & \mathrm{R}^\mathrm{C}/\pu{\mathring{A}} \text{ (Ref.2)} & \mathrm{R}^\mathrm{E}/\pu{\mathring{A}} \text{ (Ref.2)} & \mathrm{R}^\mathrm{C}/\pu{\mathring{A}} \text{ (Ref.3)} & \mathrm{R}^\mathrm{E}/\pu{\mathring{A}} \text{ (Ref.3)} & \mathrm{R}^\mathrm{TD}/\pu{\mathring{A}} \text{ (Ref.4), }r_1(r_2) \\\hline
\ce{La^2+} &1.39 & 1.25 &- & - & - \\
\ce{Ce^2+} &1.36 & 1.22 &- & - & 1.087 \ (1.160) \\
\ce{Pr^2+} &1.34 & 1.20 &- & - & 1.064 \ (1.136) \\
\ce{Nd^2+} &1.33 & 1.19 &- & - & 1.047 \ (1.113) \\
\ce{Pm^2+} &1.31 & 1.17 &- & - & - \\
\ce{Sm^2+} &1.29 & 1.15 & - & - & 1.015 \ (1.066) \\
\ce{Eu^2+} &1.28 & 1.14 & 1.31 & 1.17  & 1.012 \ (1.061) \\
\ce{Gd^2+} &1.26 & 1.12 &- & -   & 1.015 \ (1.051) \\
\ce{Tb^2+} &1.24 & 1.10 &- & - & 1.000  \ (1.038) \\
\ce{Dy^2+} &1.23 & 1.09 & 1.21 & 1.07 & 0.998  \ (1.029)\\
\ce{Ho^2+} &1.21 & 1.07 &- & - & 0.997  \ (1.018) \\
\ce{Er^2+} &1.20 & 1.06 &- & - & 0.995  \ (1.013) \\
\ce{Tm^2+} &1.18 & 1.04 & 1.17 & 1.03  & 0.989  \ (1.000) \\
\ce{Yb^2+}&1.17 & 1.03 & 1.16 & 1.02 & 0.984  \ (0.997) \\
\ce{Lu^2+} &1.16 & 1.02 &- & - & 0.983  \ (0.970)  \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
Note that the author of the Ref.2 acknowledges the crystal radii of the rare earth ions in Ref.3 has been obtained on the basis of the oxides and fluorides of rare earths, which may be a very systematic set of crystal radii of ions, and may be more reliable, although these results may be specifically for use in the oxides and fluorides. The author claims the data in their paper may suitable to use in other systems.
Also note that the paper has given an equation to calculate trivalent radii from divalent radii vise versa. The equation is:
$$\frac{R^{3+}}{R^{2+}} = 0.842 + 0.0016N_\mathrm{f}$$
where $R^{3+}$ and $R^{2+}$ are the crystal radii of the trivalent and divalent ions with six coordination, respectively, and $N_\mathrm{f}$ is the number of the $\mathrm{4f}$ electrons in the trivalent ion.
It is not relevant here but I included $r_1$ and $r_2$ of $\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{TD}$ here, which are calculated from trivalent $\ce{ML}$ and $\ce{ML2}$ complexes of lanthanide ions where $\ce{L}$s are various organic ligands. This is in case if they are useful for OP's studies.
Lastly, it is interesting to point out that, according to Ref.2, $\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{C}$ and $\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{E}$ are related by the definition $\mathrm{R}^\mathrm{C} = \mathrm{R}^\mathrm{E} +  \pu{0.14 \mathring{A}}$ (See Ref.3 & 5 for details).

References:

Suzanne C. Bart, "What is the “Lanthanide Contraction”?," Inorg. Chem. 2023, 62(9), 3713–3714 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.inorgchem.3c00440).
Y. Q. Jia, "Crystal radii and effective ionic radii of the rare earth ions," Journal of Solid State Chemistry 1991, 95(1), 184-187 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(91)90388-X).
R. D. Shannon, "Revised Effective Ionic Radii and Systematic Studies of Interatomic Distances in Halides and Chalcogenides," Acta Crystallographica Section A 1991, A32, 751-767 (DOI: https://journals.iucr.org/paper?S0567739476001551).
Vitaly Solov’ev and Alexandre Varnek, "Thermodynamic radii of lanthanide ions derived from metal-ligand complexes stability constants," Journal of Inclusion Phenomena and Macrocyclic Chemistry 2020, 98, 69–78 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1007/s10847-020-01010-0).
R. D. Shannon and C. T. Prewitt, "Effective ionic radii in oxides and fluorides," Acta Crystallographica Section B 1969, B25, 925-946 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1107/S0567740869003220).

